# How high is the tide

Tags: science

A boat has a ladder that has six rungs. Each rung is one foot apart. The bottom rung is one foot from the water. The tide rises at 12 inches every 15 minutes. High tide peaks in one hour.

When the tide is at its highest, how many rungs are under water?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Zero rungs

Because

> The boat will rise with the tide (it floats!)

Answer (score -1):

> 0, it's a trick question. Unless the boat is tied down in which case it would advance to the third rung.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in a spoiler.